# List data from a Json in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to show the data of a Json with a ListView but I cannot take the first position since it is an autogenerated String that changes for each record.

This is the Json that the API returns to me

```
{VOVQv28SU2c0GgXJKcSp8UFchPz2: 
    {email: bibiana206@gmail.com, fullname: bibiana, identification: e8104970, phone: 2095770, status: Waiting, 
        vehicle_details: 
            {car_brand: Ferrari, car_color: rojo, car_model: cretta, car_plate: az12}
    },
dBncphEFOZbzGEt5qn44sD9BYVK2: 
    {email: bolivia20192019@gmail.com, fullname: Gustavo Barrios, identification: 14326048, phone: 60697350, status: Active, 
        vehicle_details: 
            {car_brand: Renault, car_color: Gris, car_model: Duster, car_plate: AY6787,}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is transform the JSON to List like so:

```
Map<String, dynamic> json = {};

// Here you only take the values of the JSON (you ignore it's keys)
List values = json.values.toList();

// Now you can access the values of the JSON using List functions

values[0]
values.first
...
```

If you need the keys of the JSON then you can do this:

```
List<MapEntry> entries = json.entries.toList();

// Now you can access it's entries as a list like so
entries[0].key
entries[0].value
entries.first.key
entries.first.value
```

Hope this solves your issue. Let me know if it didn't

To use the data in a `ListView`

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: values.length,
  builder: (context, index) {
    final value = values[index];
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(value['fullname']),
      subtitle: Text("${value['identification']}"),
    );
  }
);
```

I would also recommend, first transform the JSON data into Data Objects. This makes the implementation more straightforward and is common practice.

Take a look at JSON serialization: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help and if this allows me to handle the data in a better way but I have a new problem again and that is that I must show the data in a ListView but it always throws me an error and I do not understand why, I am working in web flutter

Comment: Hello Gustavo, I can't help you if you don't tell me the exception you are getting.
I made an update on the answer on how to show this data in a ListView

Comment: Nothing yet I can't get the data to show this is what I'm programming https://stackoverflow.com/a/65201419/14572340

Answer (score 0):

Nothing yet I can't get the data to show this is what I'm programming

```
Future<Widget> driverItem() async {
    DatabaseSnapshot snapshot = await driverRef.once();
    Map<String, dynamic> json = snapshot.value;
    List values = json.values.toList();
    if (values.length != 0) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: values.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final value = values[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(value['fullname']),
            subtitle: Text(value['email']),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

When I run the web it returns this to me

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-database.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-auth.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-analytics.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
js_primitives.dart:47 NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'bZ' (a.bZ is not a function)
js_primitives.dart:47     at qh.Bi (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54609:15)
js_primitives.dart:47     at qh.d6 (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54568:16)
js_primitives.dart:47     at qh.eS (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54920:8)
js_primitives.dart:47     at qh.Bi (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54610:3)
js_primitives.dart:47     at qh.d6 (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54568:16)
js_primitives.dart:47     at qh.eS (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54920:8)
js_primitives.dart:47     at qh.Bi (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54610:3)
js_primitives.dart:47     at qh.d6 (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54568:16)
js_primitives.dart:47     at qh.eS (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54920:8)
js_primitives.dart:47     at wT.Bi (http://localhost:59423/main.dart.js:54610:3)
```

this is all the code on the page

```
class DriverPages extends StatefulWidget {
  static final routeName = 'DriverPage';
  DriverPages({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DriverPagesState createState() => _DriverPagesState();
}

DatabaseRef driverRef =
    FirebaseDatabaseWeb.instance.reference().child('drivers');

class _DriverPagesState extends State<DriverPages> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<Driver> items;

  Future<Widget> driverItem() async {
    DatabaseSnapshot snapshot = await driverRef.once();
    Map<String, dynamic> json = snapshot.value;
    List values = json.values.toList();
    if (values.length != 0) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: values.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final value = values[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(value['fullname']),
            subtitle: Text(value['email']),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (userSnapshot != null) {
      return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        drawer: Container(
          width: 320,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Drawer(
            child: PatimovilMenu(),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 25,
            horizontal: 30,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              PatimovilHeader(
                onPressed: () {
                  scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                },
                titlePage: 'Administrador de Conductores',
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) - 260,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Center(
                  child: driverItem() ?? Text('Nothing Drivers'),
                ),
              ),
              PatimovilFooder(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        LoginPage.routeName,
        (route) => false,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, the error messages that you are getting are not because of the ListView, it is because the Firebase scripts are not loading correctly. Please provide the web/index.html, maybe you are not declaring them correctly. Check the FlutterFire documentation for more info https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

Then you are creating a Widget inside a Future method. To do this you can use a FutureBuilder https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: I attach the HTML code,  I appreciate your help with the subject, the truth is that I have never used flutter as a frontend developer for the web

Answer (score 0):

I attach the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="patimovil_admin">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>patimovil_admin</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  
  <script src="https://api.daytonsquareroots.org/firebasedatabaseweb/v0.0.2/app.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      authDomain: "patimovil-ccb6a.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://patimovil-ccb6a.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "patimovil-ccb6a",
      storageBucket: "patimovil-ccb6a.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "25248889320",
      appId: "1:25248889320:web:b21fd8ea8fefcaadb78c5d",
      measurementId: "G-Z4D23GMTK9"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your collaboration and for showing me the error I was making, I am attaching the document that you are requesting.

```
name: patimovil_admin
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_db_web_unofficial: ^0.0.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6
  google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.1.0+8
  toast: ^0.1.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Hey Gustavo, it looks like you are doing everything right. I think the problem might be that you don't have internet connection when debugging the app? Could you please attach the pubspeck.yaml file. You need to add the Firebase dependencies there too.
Also, keep in mind that answering your own question with more code is not a good practice, you should instead edit your previous post and add it there. Also be careful, because you are posting your API keys. That should be a secret!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your collaboration and for showing me the error I was making, I am attaching the document that you are requesting.

Comment: It looks like you are doing everything fine, so I don't know what else I can do to help you. My belief is that you are debugging the code without an internet connection, so the Web Debugger tries to get the Firebase scripts (Firebase, Analytics, Auth, etc.) but it can't reach them because you don't have an internet connection.